# IAR генерирует неверный код

Tags: c, ассемблер, arm

Столкнулся с тем, что простой код работает неправильно. Имеется такой массив структур:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t DMA_SourceEndAddr;    
    uint32_t DMA_DestEndAddr;      
    uint32_t DMA_Control;          
    uint32_t DMA_Unused;           
} DMA_CtrlDataTypeDef;

DMA_CtrlDataTypeDef DMA_ControlTable[DMA_Channels_Number * (1 + DMA_AlternateData)];
```

С ним работает такая функция:

```
FlagStatus DMA_GetTransmissionFinishedStatus(uint8_t DMA_Channel)
{
    uint32_t control = DMA_ControlTable[DMA_Channel].DMA_Control;
    return (FlagStatus)(!(control & TRANSMISSION_FINISHED_MASK));
}
```

При её выполнении в переменную `control` попадает совсем не то значение, что содержится в этом поле структуры. Вот дизассемблер:

```
UXTB R0, R0
LDR.N R1, ??DataTable1.... ;Загружаем адрес массива в регистр R1
LDR R1, R1 ;Загружаем значение, содержащееся по этому указателю (зачем?), там содержится 0
ADDS.W R0, R1, R0, LSL #4 ;К регистру R0 (параметр DMA_Channel) прибавляется R1 (вычисляется адрес элемента массива)
LDR R0, [R0, #0x08] ; Берётся число не из оперативной памяти, по указателю 0x00000008
```

Получаем совсем не то число.

UPD. Если удалить инструкцию `LDR R1, R1`, то всю работает нормально.

Comment: Что такое DataTable1? Как оно связано с кодом написаным выше? это массив DMA_ControlTable? Если да, то может его нужно как-то проинициализировать?

Comment: Это массив, который генерируется компилятором, в котором хранятся адреса переменных, текстовые данные и др. Из этого массива программа и взяла адрес массива DMA_ControlTable.

Comment: **переменную control попадает совсем не то значение, что содержится в этом поле структуры** - а как Вы это обнаружили? Поставили оператор печати *printf('..", поле, переменная)* ? Я подозреваю, что переменная получает значение правильно, но затем это значение затирается какой-то ошибкой адресации.

Comment: @Sergey, обнаружил это через отладчик. А потом через анализ дизассемблера увидел, какое именно значение попадает в переменную.

Comment: @maestro И контрольная точка была прямо на операторе объявления и инициализации переменной *control* ? Ну тогда - последняя идея: может быть параметр *DMA_Channel* имеет "не то" значение? И выбор структуры из массива идёт по неверному индексу?

Comment: @Sergey, вы смотрели дизассемблер? Он показывает, откуда именно берётся значение. Значение берётся по указателю 0x00000008, а не из массива.

Comment: @maestro, не обращайте внимание, там комментратор похоже не совсем "въезжает". ;) У меня другое предположение, если это баг компилятора, может стоит попробовать другую версию? Также поиграйтесь с ключами оптимизации, если таковые пристуствуют.